# Silent install of Github-for-windows

Tags: windows, github, silent-install

I would like to silent install GitHub on Windows. I have downloaded GitHubSetup.exe from https://windows.github.com/.

I am used to pass other parameters like `/S`, `INSTALLDIR` etc. to silent install programs.

How to silent install GitHub in a preferred directory and which `URL` should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github for Windows uses the Microsoft ClickOnce installer for deployment<sup>[[1]](https://help.github.com/articles/uninstalling-github-for-windows#removing-files-left-behind)</sup>.  ClickOnce is a per user based installation technology and does not support silent installs.

The [Chocolatey package management system](https://chocolatey.org/) for Windows does have a [package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/githubforwindows) for GfW which relies on Auto Hot Key to automate the installation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have installed Chocolatey and subsequently silent installed GitHubForWindows by executing `cinst githubforwindows`

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo Off
REM script to install GitHub Desktop
REM Installs the machine-wide installer
msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0GitHubDesktopSetup-x64.msi" /qn
REM Wait for install to complete
PING -n 10 127.0.0.1>nul
REM Change directory to install folder and run exe
CD "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\GitHub Desktop Deployment" && "GitHubDesktopDeploymentTool.exe" -s
REM Delete desktop shortcut
Del /f "C:\Users%username%\Desktop\GitHub Desktop.lnk"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands in windows cmd.exe to install git silently:

```
powershell -command "& { (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.21.0.windows.1/Git-2.21.0-64-bit.exe', 'c:\git_setup.exe') }"
"C:\git_setup.exe"  /VERYSILENT
```